# Python Turn something inside a string to a variable

Tags: python

I want to do an output name for a file and the input will/should be like this:

```
"seriesName Episode epNr 720p"
```

and I want to turn the *seriesName* and the *epNr* to variables I set.
For example:

```
seriesName="Mr. Robot"
epNr=10
```

and if I do print(output), the output should be

```
"Mr. Robot Episode 10 720p"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str.replace`:

```
myString = "seriesName Episode epNr 720p"
replacedString = myString.replace('seriesName', 'Mr. Robot').replace('epNr', '10')
print(replacedString)
```

Or better yet, use `str.format` with keyword arguments:

```
In [1]: myString = "{seriesName} Episode {epNr} 720p"    
In [2]: myString.format(seriesName='Mr. Robot', epNr='10')
Out[3]: 'Mr. Robot Episode 10 720p'
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general way of achieving the same:

```
seriesName="Mr. Robot"
epNr=10

print "{} Episode {} 720p".format(seriesName,epNr)
```